# Is there anything that can keep track of my installed npm packages and restore them on a different dev environment ? (like "Restore NuGet packages")

Tags: node.js, npm

So I'm new to node/npm packages. Here's the scenario.

- I installed all the dependencies on an environment.
- Pushed the code to a remote repo
- Pulled the code to a different dev environment.
- Tried to restore all the previously installed dependencies
  automatically but couldn't figure out a way.

---

I worked with NuGet packages before. I was expecting something similar to the behavior of ***"Restore NuGet Packages".***
I've looked into my **packages.json** file but they don't list the later installed dependencies like **packages.config** file would do in case of NuGet. So is there anything similar? or am a missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `package.json` file is doing what you are looking for. Installing a dependency with `--save` option will add it to the `package.json` dependency list. On another environment you can install same dependencies with running `npm install` command.

1. Install a dependency for the first time: `npm install newpackage --save`
2. Push the `package.json` to the repo
3. Pull the repo
4. Install **all** dependencies which listed in package.json file by running `npm install` command in the directory which `package.json` reside

Comment: Thanks. Followed this workflow, now It's working as I expected. What I did wrong was, running `--save` on a different directory, resulting in a separate `package.json` file.